# Display image view on the top of the Navigation Bar in IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, navigationbar

I am creating a view using XIB as below attached image. But my problem is if i am setting image view over navigation bar and status bar, then image is coming properly but not able to see my view navigation bar title, background color and back button. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong. Should i need to add Navigation bar in Image view?

here is my code :

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.strImage];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if (imageData) {
    ivImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
else{
    ivImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Avatar-Retake_Profile.png"];
}
```

my xib :

[image]

my output screen :

[image]

screen (i am getting now using my code) :

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the image below the bar? This looks fine. You aren't doing anything "wrong". What do you want to have happen?

Comment: @doctordoberThanks..please check my update question, i have attached my output.

Comment: I see your output view and I still don't see anything wrong with it. What is the problem?

Comment: my problem is, title name and back button is not visible. It's hiding from image.

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with the image. Your navigation bar is just completely hidden. Are you sure this viewcontroller is embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: I am adding navigation bar on my view directly from XIB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56758/discussion-between-doctordoder-and-anand-gautam).